# solving non-linear systems inequalities

Tags: reference-request, inequality, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve a non-linear systems of 14 inequalities  with 12 variables, involving exponential and polynomial functions. I have been searching over the web for leads,but without any success.I know how to solve non-linear system of equations numerically.
By solving I mean getting all feasible points.

So, what are the possible ways in which non-linear system of inequalities can be solved numerically?

Any links to text which discusses this issue would be great.